# Save SQL data in PHP array

Tags: php, mysql

I want to save all rows with matching id to an array but I can't get it working. What do I have to add?

```
    public function getProjects($db1) {
    $id= $this->getId($db1);

    $projects = $db1->getResult(
        sprintf(
            "SELECT * FROM projects WHERE id =1"
        )
    );
    return $projects;
}
```

So projects only returns the first item in my database, and not all.

And yes I've seen similar questions but those options don't work for me since I use PHP7 or maybe it has something to do with sprintf.
Who can help?

Comment: Well, if id is your primary key, using `where id = 1` obviously you will only get exactly one record if one exists with that id.

Comment: It's not the primary key, it isn't unique either. There are more projects with id 1.

Comment: ok, I see and what library are you using for querying the db?

Comment: I didn't mean the db-technology itself but how you connect and execute your query. `$db1->getResult(..)`. What is this doing? .

Comment: Sorry for that. I found the issue, the library used is sitecomposer and the getResult function only returns one value, in this case one row.

Answer (score 3):

see the usage of sprintf() in php from the following link:http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_sprintf.asp

Answer (score 3):

So, let me get this straight:

You want to **get results from a database** and, then, **group the results by id**, i.e, build an **array that aggregates all rows with same id**. Am I right?

If it is so, you can do it like this (example):

```
$projects = [];
$projects[] = ["id" => 1, "name" => "project1"];
$projects[] = ["id" => 2, "name" => "project2"];
$projects[] = ["id" => 1, "name" => "project11"];
$projects[] = ["id" => 2, "name" => "project22"];

$projectsById = [];
foreach($projects as $project) {
   if(!isset($projectsById[$project['id']]))
      $projectsById[$project['id']] = [];
   $projectsById[$project['id']][] = $project;
}

var_dump($projectsById);
```

Quick explanation:

- Foreach record from the database,

  - if the record ID doesn't exists on array $projectsById, it's created a new (nested) array having the record ID as key of that new array: `$projectsById[$project['id']] = [];`
  - Now, all the next records with the same id will be put on the above created array: `$projectsById[$project['id']][] = $project;`

You can check the result and play with the code here: http://ideone.com/AcoLIQ

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was an function within sitecomposer designed to only return one value (first row where statement succeeds).